# Trouble Reading .xlsx Files from a Local Server in Cloudera Data Science Workbench (CDSW)

Tags: cdsw

Hello Stack Overflow Community,
I'm using glob to loop through a directory containing .xlsx files on a local server (referred by UNC paths). The issue is that I keep running into a "No objects to concatenate" error.

Code Snippet:

```
dfs = []

for filepath in glob.glob(r"\local_server\folder\abc.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(filepath, engine='openpyxl')
    dfs.append(df)
```

Are there any CDSW-specific settings or permissions that I might be overlooking? Is it possible to read in excel files from a shared server drive? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering, "No objects to concatenate," typically occurs when you're trying to concatenate pandas DataFrames and there are no DataFrames in the list to concatenate.

It seems like you're attempting to read a single Excel file from a UNC path using glob.glob(), but glob.glob() returns a list of file paths, and you're iterating over it as if it were a list of paths.

I would recommend putting the `r'...'` string literal modifier in front. And also `\\` after `r'...'`.

So your code should look like this:

```
dfs = []

for filepath in glob.glob(r'\\local_server\folder\abc.xlsx'):
    df = pd.read_excel(filepath, engine='openpyxl')
    dfs.append(df)
```